# Javascript firstly get datas specific key from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array like that

```
array[{ channel: "", data: { title: "", type: "", thumbnail: "" } }]
```

for some elements type is live,

and i want to list all of items but first which has live for type

also im getting datas with .map for listing .

thx!

Comment: only sorting type live first and anything else like alpahabetical to some other field as second criteria?

Comment: yes. i have channels and want to sort first lives then others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.sort()`

```js
let arr = [
  { channel: "", data: { title: "", type: "adsfadsf", thumbnail: "" } },
  { channel: "", data: { title: "", type: "live", thumbnail: "" } },
  { channel: "", data: { title: "", type: "live", thumbnail: "" } },
  { channel: "", data: { title: "", type: "blabla", thumbnail: "" } },
  { channel: "", data: { title: "", type: "blubla", thumbnail: "" } },
  { channel: "", data: { title: "", type: "live", thumbnail: "" } },
  { channel: "", data: { title: "", type: "live", thumbnail: "" } },
  { channel: "", data: { title: "", type: "adsfadsf", thumbnail: "" } }
];

let result = [...arr].sort(({ data: { type } }) => (type === "live" ? -1 : 0));

console.log(arr);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thx for comment. actually i get datas with map. is it possible do it in map ? cause the data in state

Comment: @crystalcyber take a look. you can use the spread operator here `[...arr]` it will not modify the original array

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
  { channel: "ARD", data: { title: "", type: "", thumbnail: "" } },
  { channel: "ZDF", data: { title: "", type: "live", thumbnail: "" } },
  { channel: "SAT1", data: { title: "", type: "live", thumbnail: "" } },
  { channel: "RTL", data: { title: "", type: "", thumbnail: "" } }
];

let result = arr.sort((a,b) => {
    aType = a.data.type;
    bType = b.data.type;
    if (aType=='live')
        return (bType!='live') ? -1 : a.channel.localeCompare(b.channel.localeCompare);
    else
        return (bType=='live') ? 1 : a.channel.localeCompare(b.channel.localeCompare);
});

console.log(result);
```